# Displaying images horizontally CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float, alignment

Imhaving a bit of difficulty with CSS styling on my website, Currently I have a row of images that I'd like to align horizontally along my page. But just now it displays them all vertically in a row and I'm not sure why. All the images are stored in an array, it's just getting them lined up that's the problem. 
here is my code:

```
   .img{
float:left;
width:120px;
margin:auto;
margin-left:10px;
padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: Copy/pasted your code into jsfiddle, and the images are displayed horizontally. What does your HTML look like? http://jsfiddle.net/aWTKf/1/

Comment: Just realised my img's are stored inside a div called theimgs. That could be doing it?

Comment: If each img is in it's own div, then yes. or if the container div is too narrow. It would be easier to help if you posted the relevant HTML though ;)

Comment: You could also style the divs to be inline-block.

Comment: "or if the container div is too narrow" Boom problem solved @xec kudos

Comment: Fiddle or it didn't happen

Answer (score 0):

You should add the to your style `display:inline-block`. The `inline-block` value makes, that your .img is not displayed with a new-line at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Images by default are `display: inline`. This means they will not clear other elements horizontally by default IF there is space in their container. Adjust the width of the parent container of the image elements: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/arniemandla/263gqLp4/3/)

If you want your images to expand horizontally irrespective of container width, use `display: table-cell` in the style (css) in a div wrapping each image element: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/arniemandla/evqn3x19/)