# How Do You Display Images In A Horizontal Row?

Tags: php, html

Here is my code that returns a list of pictures, depending on how many of clients are connected to my server.

```
    <div>
<?php
$Query = new MinecraftQuery( );

try
{
    $Query->Connect( '64.31.40.146', 25575 );

    if(($Players = $Query->GetPlayers()) !== false) {
        foreach($Players as $Player) {
            echo "<img title=".$Player." src=https://minotar.net/avatar/".$Player."/32.png>
                <p>"."</p>";
        }
    } 
}
catch( MinecraftQueryException $e )
{
    echo $e->getMessage( );
}
?>
</div>
```

Though, when I do this. It displays the images stacked vertically.

http://i.imgur.com/FwvNAlB.png

What would be the best way to force the images to go horizontally?

Comment: images by default are inline meaning they will automatically go horizontally. You are adding a `<p>` tag after the image which will add a new line and force each image on it's own line.

Comment: @CGSmith105 The question is not about divs or centering them.

Comment: "What would be the best way to force the images to go horizontally?" By not doing the thing that you're doing which is explicitly forcing them to go vertically.

Comment: @Juhana misread.  [here is another q/a that solves it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999421/displaying-images-horizontally-css)

Comment: That one's not relevant either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to you have `<p>` tag. Change your echo for this:

```
echo "<img title=".$Player." src=https://minotar.net/avatar/".$Player."/32.png>";
```

By default `<p>` tag change line.

Comment: Just an FYI, html tags can be put inside code blocks (back ticks for inline or 4 spaces at the start of the line for block) to display the tag instead of parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the

```
<p>"."</p>
```

I don't know why you are adding it, but that is causing the problem. 
Also add quotes and and a final "/" to the img tag.

So that line would be:

```
echo "<img title='".$Player."' src='https://minotar.net/avatar/".$Player."/32.png' />";
```

Comment: You don't need to self-close img tags unless you're working with XHTML.

Comment: Yeah, of course, but it is a good practice to do it in order to avoid problems! Thanks